# What did POKE 842,13 on Atari do? (Jamming the Return key)

Tags: atari, memory-layout

In quite a few programs on Atari, I found the self-programming trick:

```
10 GRAPHICS 0           : REM clear the screen, enter standard text mode
20 POSITION 2,4         : REM place cursor 4 lines from top of screen
30 PRINT "1000 SOUND 0, 200, 10, 15      : REM Beep"
40 PRINT "1010 FOR I=0 TO 500 : NEXT I   : REM wait a bit"
50 PRINT "1020 SOUND 0, 0, 0, 0          : REM Silence"
60 PRINT "1030 RETURN"
70 PRINT "CONT"
80 POSITION 2,0         : REM place cursor on top of screen
90 POKE 842,13          : REM The Magical POKE
100 STOP                : REM Abort program execution
110 POKE 842,12         : REM Program resumes from here. This stops the effect of the prior POKE
120 GOSUB 1000          : REM Emit the Beep
130 END
```

The above program appends to itself a subroutine that emits a beep, then executes it. The uses in practice were much more creative.

The key point is `POKE 842,13` which causes effect similar to holding down the Return key - the cursor starts riding down the screen, executing whatever's printed out - including `CONT` which resumes the program.

I found memory location 842 is [ICAX1](http://www.atarimax.com/freenet/freenet_material/12.AtariLibrary/2.MiscellaneousTextFiles/showarticle.php?30) not very informatively described as *The auxiliary information bytes are used to give CIO or the device any special information needed.* Bits 2 and 3 are responsible for Read and Write flags when opening a file... but I didn't find anything about bit 0, plus no file is being accessed here.

So, 'from the guts side' what did that POKE do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If bit 0 of location 842 is set then the keyboard scanning routine immediately returns 0x9B which is the code indicating the ENTER key has been pressed.  In short, a surprisingly literal effect.

The keyboard scan is part of the "OS" ROM built into the machine.  There's a source listing I'll excerpt from: [Atari 800 ROM OS Source Listing](https://atariwiki.org/wiki/Wiki.jsp?page=Atari%20800%20ROM%20OS%20Source%20Listing)

`ICAX1Z` is a zero page location that is a temporary copy of location 842.  If you know 6502 assembly language you can quickly see that the keyboard scan routine returns 0x9B when bit 0 of `ICAX1Z` is set:

```
; SYSTEM EOL (CARRIAGE RETURN)
CR      =    $9B
;...
KGETCH: LDA  ICAX1Z    ;TEST LSB OF AUX1 FOR SPECIAL EDITOR READ MO
        LSR   A
        BCS   GETOUT
;...
GETOUT: LDA   #CR      ;PUT CR IN ATACHR
        BNE   K8       ;(UNCONDITIONAL)
;....
K8:     STA   ATACHR
K4:     JMP   RETUR1   ;ALL DONE
```

Additionally there are some equates which give the purpose of each bit in `AUX1` portion of the I/O Control Block of each device.  Most of the bits are generic (i.e., the mean the same to all devices), but `$1` (bit 0) does seem to have a special meaning:

```
; AUX1 EQUATES
; () INDICATES WHICH DEVICES USE BIT
APPEND  =     $1          ;OPEN FOR WRITE APPEND (D), OR SCREEN READ (
DIRECT  =     $2          ;OPEN FOR DIRECTORY ACCESS (D)
OPNIN   =     $4          ;OPEN FOR INPUT (ALL DEVICES)
OPNOT   =     $8          ;OPEN FOR OUTPUT (ALL DEVICES)
OPNINO  =     OPNIN+OPNOT ;OPEN FOR INPUT AND OUTPUT (ALL DEVICES)
MXDMOD  =     $10         ;OPEN FOR MIXED MODE (E,S)
INSCLR  =     $20         ;OPEN WITHOUT CLEARING SCREEN (E,S)
```

The OS defines several devices including the keyboard, cassette, printer and disk each with a corresponding I/O Control Block (or IOCB).  You'll notice that the normal value for 842 is 12 which means `OPNIN` and `OPNOT` are both set.  The device is open for read and write access.  When you `POKE` 13 into 842 the `APPEND` bit is set.  For the cassette or disk that might mean you're adding to the end of a file.  For the keyboard device it has the special effect you're wondering about.

Note that `POKE 842,4` has no obvious effect - BASIC never tries to write to the keyboard so turning off `OPNOT` does nothing.  But a `POKE 842,8` is bad.  BASIC will spew an undending stream of `ERROR - 131` messages as it tries to read input from the keyboard but is denied because read access has been turned off.